# Is the homomorphic image of a G-domain is G-domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have no idea how to prove this if it is true or to give a counter example if it is not true.

Is the homomorphic image of a G-domain is a G-domain?

A G-domain is an integral domain $R$ with quotient field $F$ such that there exists $0\neq{a}\in{R}$ such that $F=R[\frac{1_{R}}{a}]$.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, what's a $G$-domain? Have you tried it on any examples yet?

Comment: Every integral domain which is not a field has a homomorphic image that is not an integral domain. For this trivial reason, an image of a G-domain is not necessarily a G-domain.

Comment: @PavelC: Excellent result! Could you please provide me the reference where I can find this result?

Comment: @Algebra: I do not have any reference for this. It is just a restatement of the fact that every commutative ring which is not a zero ring or a field has a proper ideal which is not prime ideal (then the homomorphism is the projection modulo that ideal). I suspect this is a fact which is usually taken for granted, so there are no proofs of the fact in literature. It can be proved using the Nakayama's lemma, though. But it is probably a little off-topic.

Comment: No no! Nakayama's Lemma is completely related to this topics. So, I think you are in right track.

Comment: I really think we're interested in the quotients $R/\mathfrak p$ where $\mathfrak p$ is prime. As @PavelC indicates the problem is otherwise a trivial matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still seems a little off-topic, however...

**Claim:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring which is not a zero ring or a field. Then $R$ contains a proper ideal $I$ which is not prime.

*Proof:* Assume the contrary, i.e. every proper ideal of $R$ is prime.

1) Suppose $I,J$ are arbitrary ideals of $R$. Then $IJ \subseteq I \cap J \subseteq I,J$. If $IJ \subsetneq I, IJ \subsetneq J,$ the ideal $IJ$ is not prime (just take $x \in I \setminus IJ, y \in J \setminus IJ$. Then $xy \in IJ, x,y \notin IJ$). Therefore $IJ=I\cap J=I$ or $IJ=I\cap J=J$. Thus, $I\subseteq J$ or $J \subseteq I$, hence $R$ is unserial.

2) In particular, the Jacobson radical of $R$ is its only maximal ideal, say $M$. Consider any finitely generated ideal $I$ of $R$. Then, by the same argumentation as above, we have $IM=I$ (the case $IM=M$ can occur only if $I=M$, since we have $I \subseteq M$). By Nakayama's lemma, this implies $I=0$. This is a contradiction (every nonzero ring has  a nonzero finitely generated ideal). QED

(EDIT: A much simpler argument is given by Karl Kronenfeld in comments.)

Now, consider a G-domain $R$ and its ideal $I$ which is not prime. Then the image of the canonical projection $\pi_I:R \rightarrow R/I$ is not an integral domain, in particular, it is not a G-domain.

Comment: Perhaps quicker is to pick any nonzero $f$ and note that $(f^2)$ is prime, so $f=f^2g$ for some $g$. But that is the same as $f(1-fg)=0$ and since $R$ is an integral domain $fg=1$.

Comment: By "proper" I want to avoid the whole ring, which is not a prime ideal by definition. So $0$ is meant as a proper ideal in the answer above.

Comment: @PavelC wow, using nakayama to prove exercise #1 in Kaplansky's commutative ring book is the best thermonuclear proof I've seen in a while :)

Comment: This is really an excellent work! Thanks!

Comment: @rschwieb: I agree it is kind of clumsy. : ) it was earlyin the morning when I wrote it.